# How to free a char* that is being returned from another function?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, free

Let's say we have the following scenario.

```
char* halfString(char* input) {
    char* output = malloc(strlen(input));
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++)
        output[i] == input[i];
    output[i] = '\0';
    return output;
}

int main() {
    char* input = "Hello";
    char* output = halfString(input);
    printf("%s\n",output);
    free(output);
}
```

Will the call "free(output)" free the memory of char* output that is local to main and free the memory of the char* output local to halfString()? OR is there still a memory leak for the char* output local to halfString()?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may also want to actually allocate enough space. You're currently one `char` short. `strlen()`, which you should only be calling once and saving to a local to use for your enumeration, returns the length *without* the terminator. Your math should use `strlen(input)+1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no memory leak.

You seem to be confused, though, about how heap allocation works. There is only *one* chunk of memory being allocated here, and it is not "local" to either `halfString()` or to `main()`. The allocated chunk exists in the heap, and is not scoped to a particular code block.

`malloc()` returns a pointer to it. You then return that pointer back to `main()`, but the value of the pointer is still the same: it points to the same address in memory, the same chunk of heap. `main()` then properly frees it.

As a design consideration, this is often not the best thing to do. In general, a caller may not necessarily know that the pointer returned by `halfString()` points to a chunk that was allocated with `malloc()` and that they need to `free()` it. This would have to be very clearly and carefully documented. A better solution might be to provide a `freeHalfString()` function which does the freeing; then from a maintenance standpoint, those two functions can be put in the same place and maintained concurrently, so that the caller doesn't need to worry about how the buffer was allocated, or how to free it.

(As others have pointed out, you also have a buffer overflow because you need to allocate `strlen(input) + 1` bytes to include the NULL terminator.)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing two related items: buffers, and pointers. A buffer is a block of memory which, in the context of your question, is allocated using `malloc()`. A pointer is related in that it points to a buffer, but it's not the buffer itself.

In your `halfString()` function, you allocate a buffer, and you store the address of (pointer to) that buffer in your local `output`.You then return it to the caller, `main()`, which coincidentally has a variable of the same name which will point to the same buffer.

Now, in `main()`, when you `free(output);` you're not freeing a pointer, you're freeing the buffer that pointer points to. It doesn't matter where the buffer was allocated, it only matters that the buffer was allocated (and not already freed). After this call your main function's `output` variable still exists, and it still has an address to what was once a valid buffer -- but that buffer must not be used of course, since it's no longer valid.

Now as to your question "Is there a memory leak?" -- You've malloc'd a single buffer, then you free'd that same buffer, so no link. Always properly pair a malloc with a free, and you'll be in good shape.

Answer (score 2):

The code is mostly correct, because `malloc()` puts memory on the heap and `free()` frees it.  It does not matter which functions they get called from.

That said, there is an important off-by-one error:

```
char* output = malloc(strlen(input) + 1); // Don't forget +1
```

The `strlen()` function returns the number of characters in the string, *not including the terminator.*

These errors can be often caught automatically by using certain tools like Mudflap (compile with `-fmudflap`, if using GCC) and Valgrind.

### Algorithmic complexity

There is a problem with the algorithmic complexity of your code, which will probably disappear with good compilers when optimization is enabled.

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++)
```

This will call `strlen()`, which is O(N), and it will call `strlen()` O(N) times, giving O(N<sup>2</sup>) asymptotic performance.  We can do better, here are two fixes:

```
// Version 1
size_t i, n = strlen(input);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    ...

// Version 2
size_t i;
for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `free()` will free the memory allocated in called function itself. it is not local to any function because `malloc allocates memory on heap`.
what you call as `local memory` is on `stack` that will be freed when function returns.
So what allocation done using `malloc` is on `heap` and the procedure you used will free memory allocated in called function.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work correctly (if the off-by-one error others mention is fixed).  The call in `main` will free the memory allocated in `halfString`.

There is no "memory of output that is local to main".  What is local to main is the output pointer, which was allocated on the stack and will go out of scope when main exits.

Answer (score 0):

There is no memory leak. System knows how much memmory is associated with pointer, and since you can not free part of memory block allocated with malloc, it will free all.